# NS_Error_Interception_Failed on Firefox

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

All the APIs are working perfectly on chrome while on firefox none of the API works. All the api fails with error **NS_Error_Interception_Failed**. I am using **axios** for performing the API calls.

[image]

```
const submitLogin = () => {
    setFormError({
      emailError: "",
      passwordError: "",
    });
    setRequestingServer(true);
    if (!requestingServer) {
      if (!isForgotPassword) {
        if (!validEmail(loginForm.username)) {
          setFormError({
            emailError: "Username is not valid",
            passwordError: "",
          });
          setRequestingServer(false);
          return;
        } else if (!validPassword(loginForm.password)) {
          setFormError({
            emailError: "",
            passwordError:
              "Password must have minimum 6 characters and contain at least 1 UPPERCASE, 1 lower case and 1 number.",
          });
          setRequestingServer(false);
          return;
        }
        login(loginForm).then((res) => {
          console.log("loginFormResp", res);
          if (res?.data.status) {
            setRedirect(true);
          }
          setRequestingServer(false);
        });
      } else {
        if (!validEmail(loginForm.username)) {
          setFormError({
            emailError: "Email is not valid",
            passwordError: "",
          });
          setRequestingServer(false);
          return;
        }
        requestPassword({ username: loginForm.username }).then((res) => {
          setRequestingServer(false);
        });
      }
    }
  };

  if (redirect === true) {
    return state?.from && state?.from !== "/" ? (
      <Redirect to={state?.from} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} />
    );
  }
```

Already verified cors headers on node.js server and it seems to be good.

Comment: The issue was at the layer of interception. On login request the authorization request header was undefined. This behaviour occurs with build only. In serve mode this works good.